# Adding then Referencing multiple values within IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC. I have the following code in my method:

```
// Get list of news formats that were ticked  
IEnumerable<int> newsFormatIds = viewModel.ClubNewsFormats
     .Where(c => c.selected == true).
     Select(c => c.NewsFormatId);
// Copy news formats
IEnumerable<ClubNewsFormat> clubNewsFormats = club.ClubNewsFormats.ToList();
// Remove previous formats
foreach (ClubNewsFormat previousClubNewsFormats in clubNewsFormats)
{
    db.ClubNewsFormats.Remove(previousClubNewsFormats);
}
// Add new club news formats
foreach (int NewsFormatId in newsFormatIds)
{
    NewsFormat newsFormat = db.NewsFormats.Find(NewsFormatId);

    var newClubNewsFormat = new ClubNewsFormat {
            ClubId = club.ClubId,
            NewsFormatId = newsFormat.NewsFormatId,
            Discount =  
    };

    db.ClubNewsFormats.Add(newClubNewsFormat);
}
```

It gets a list of the items that were ticked in a view and then adds a record for each to the ClubNewsFormats table. By using the IEnumerable to generate a list of all the Model.ClubNewsFormats[c].NewsFormatId where Model.ClubNewsFormats[c].selected is true. As well as being able to select the the Id's you can also add a Discount for each Id. I want to be able to commit this Discount value for each Selected Id when saving them to the ClubNewsFormats Table.

How to I add the Discount to the IEnumerable as well as the Id so that I can commit it in the foreach (int NewsFormatId in newsFormatIds) loop?

The section of the view is:

```
@for (int c = 0; c < Model.ClubNewsFormats.Count(); c++)
{
<div>
@Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.ClubNewsFormats[c].NewsFormatId)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.ClubNewsFormats[c].selected)
@Html.LabelFor(x => Model.ClubNewsFormats[c].Format, Model.ClubNewsFormats[c].Format)
@Html.EditorFor(x => Model.ClubNewsFormats[c].Discount)
</div>
}
```

The view model is:

```
    public class ClubNewsFormatsViewModel
{   
    public int NewsFormatId { get; set; }

    public string Format { get; set; }

    public bool selected { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Discount")]
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
}
```

which is referenced in the main view model by:

```
public ClubNewsFormatsViewModel[] ClubNewsFormats { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is not clear to me - where do you need to add the property? IEnumerable is a system-defined interface, you definitely can't add anything to that. Where do you need to access the value?

Comment: Hopefully my edit has made it a little clearer, apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I amended to controller to this:

```
// Remove previous formats
foreach (ClubNewsFormat previousClubNewsFormats in clubNewsFormats)
    {
         db.ClubNewsFormats.Remove(previousClubNewsFormats);
    }
    // Add new club news formats
foreach (ClubNewsFormatsViewModel clubNewsFormat in viewModel.ClubNewsFormats.Where(c => c.selected == true))
    {
         var newClubNewsFormat = new ClubNewsFormat { ClubId = club.ClubId, NewsFormatId = clubNewsFormat.NewsFormatId, Discount = clubNewsFormat.Discount };

         db.ClubNewsFormats.Add(newClubNewsFormat);
     }
```